# Does Selenium Webdriver Performance Related to RAM Capacity?

Tags: java, selenium, memory, webdriver

I would like to ask something in general about Selenium Webdriver.

I am using Selenium Webdriver in an Eclipse project which utilize TestNG. Sometimes tests are failing randomly, but when they are re-run most of the time it passes. I suspect that this had something to do with the memory available on the PC because the application that is being tested itself takes much memory (around 1.8 GBs of RAM) where my RAM is 8GB.

I wonder if the performance of Selenium Webdriver may decrease if there is only little memory left on the machine? Most of the time I start to run the automation test, the machine has reached around 70% of memory usage excluding browser's memory usage.

Thank you.

Comment: It's going to have some impact but won't be the single problem. We'll need concrete examples to go on before advising any further.

Answer (score 1):

I would say Yes and No

Yes because **Everything** is affected by remain resources, not just Selenium Webdriver. If you give enough resource for it, it could run well.

No because selenium doesnot cost too much resource. The point here when you run a new instance of webdriver, it will launch a new browser; and browser costs lot of memory. Hence, your selenium performance in this case is browser performance vs memory

So, my suggestion for you

1 - Balance the number of your tests (I assumed you run parallel tests)

2 - Build a retry mechanism (I recommended, but other may not)

Hope it could help